# Magento 2 Integration signature

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, integration

I'm trying to integrate my M2 store with my 3rd party service by using oAuth.
Based on information from here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html - I need to:

- Get a request token
- Get an access token

I'm making valid POST request from my service back to my M2 store with that fields:

```
oauth_consumer_key
oauth_nonce
oauth_signature_method
oauth_timestamp
oauth_version
oauth_signature
```

Unfortunatelly my `oauth_signature` is every time wrong. I'm receving this response: `oauth_problem=Invalid+signature`
I tried many ways how to create `oauth_signature` - with different quotes, with different order of values, with different encoding etc. No luck.

Could anybody show an example in a raw PHP of a working `request token` method please?

Comment: Did you created an integration in `System > Extensions > Integrations`?

Comment: Yeah, it's installed already and has all config set. I was able to "Allow" and navigate to my 3rd party service but then after process which described in link above  - I have message in log from response (Invalid signature)

Comment: Did you use POSTMAN to send request? This field is automatically set